# New virtualenv environment listing several packages I have not installed

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv and have recently created a fresh environment yet it lists several packaged as installed although I haven't done so.

Here is an example:

```
user@computer:~/Desktop$ virtualenv ENV
New python executable in ENV/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
user@computer:~/Desktop$ cd ENV/
user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV$ ls
bin  include  lib  local
user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV$ . bin/activate
(ENV)user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV$ pip list
Django (1.7.4)
pbr (0.10.7)
pip (6.0.7)
setuptools (12.0.5)
six (1.9.0)
stevedore (1.2.0)
virtualenv (12.0.6)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.5)
virtualenvwrapper (4.3.2)
```

However, if I deactivate the envionment, I get the global list of packages installed and its not the same list.

```
(ENV)user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV$ deactivate
user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV$ pip list
adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.4)
apt-xapian-index (0.45)
chardet (2.0.1)
command-not-found (0.3)
debtagshw (0.1)
defer (1.0.6)
dirspec (13.10)
Django (1.7.4)
duplicity (0.6.23)
httplib2 (0.8)
lockfile (0.8)
lxml (3.3.3)
oauthlib (0.6.1)
oneconf (0.3.7)
PAM (0.4.2)
pbr (0.10.7)
pexpect (3.1)
Pillow (2.3.0)
pip (6.0.7)
piston-mini-client (0.7.5)
psycopg2 (2.4.5)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycups (1.9.66)
pycurl (7.19.3)
pygobject (3.12.0)
pygpgme (0.3)
pyOpenSSL (0.13)
pyserial (2.6)
pysmbc (1.0.14.1)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu1)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
pyxdg (0.25)
reportlab (3.0)
requests (2.2.1)
sessioninstaller (0.0.0)
setuptools (3.3)
six (1.9.0)
software-center-aptd-plugins (0.0.0)
stevedore (1.2.0)
system-service (0.1.6)
Twisted-Core (13.2.0)
Twisted-Web (13.2.0)
unity-lens-photos (1.0)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
virtualenv (12.0.6)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.5)
virtualenvwrapper (4.3.2)
xdiagnose (3.6.3build2)
zope.interface (4.0.5)
```

Could this have anything to do with my python paths?

Comment: What happens if you initialize the virtualenv with the --no-site-packages flag? E.g. $: virtualenv Env --no-site-packages

Comment: I can't edit it well, but I-m getting the same response.


`user@computer:~/Desktop$ virtualenv ENV2 --no-site-packages`
`New python executable in ENV2/bin/python`
`Installing setuptools, pip...done.`
`user@computer:~/Desktop$ cd ENV2`
`user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV2$ ls`
`bin  include  lib  local`
`user@computer:~/Desktop/ENV2$ . bin/activate`
`(ENV2)felipe@computer:~/Desktop/ENV2$ pip list`
`Django (1.7.4)`
`pbr (0.10.7)`